# How to show string with spaces as single string?

Tags: string, bash, split

I'm getting strings with `|` as separator from an `awk` script and being stored in variable `a`

Then I like to be able to split the content of `a` for further processing.

this is the script I have so far (using the split procedure in this thread [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)).

```
a=(`awk 'BEGIN{
        x="how are you"; y="fine"; z="and you?";
        printf("%s|%s|%s",x,y,z)}'`)

b=(${a//|/ })
```

My current output when I try to see the separated parts of `a` is this:

```
$ echo ${b[0]}
how

$ echo ${b[1]}

$ echo ${b[2]}
```

and my desired output would be:

```
$ echo ${b[0]}
how are you

$ echo ${b[1]}
fine

$ echo ${b[2]}
and you?
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why is `$a` an array?

Comment: The method you're using won't work if there are spaces in the values, because those will also be delimiters after you replace the `|` with spaces.

Comment: Use the accepted answer in the question you linked to, which sets `IFS` to the delimiter.

Comment: Use [Johannes Schaub - litb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash/918931#918931) (which is the accepted one, but isn't listed first for some reason. Something like storing the string with `a=$(awk ...)`, then splitting it into an array with `IFS='|' read -ra b <<< "$a"`. Alternately, you could use process substitution to do it one step: `IFS='|' read -ra b < <(awk ...)`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks Gordon. I've opened a new thread with a better example using your suggestion in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77709332/avoid-splitting-string-by-space-in-output-stored-in-bash-array